# Is file link hyperlink protocol not supported in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, hyperlink, file

Hyperlink which opens a file locally on SharePoint Fails (2016/2019).

When selecting the link, the console reports:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file://

If right click and select copy link and paste it into a new tab, the browser opens the file hyperlink protocol from the local location.

Understanding [SharePoint has this statement this protocol is not supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/promoted-link-invalid-url), has anyone created a work around to this matter? Besides the step above of copy and paste?

Answer (score 0):

you can not add a local resource link File:// in sharepoint directly.

But there is work around.

If you wish to get link of some local, convert it in a network storage/file.  create a shortcut of network location and add the shortcut link to a document library.

Comment: 1. Make Short to File
2. Add ShortCut to Document Library on SharePoint
3. Create HyperLink which points at ShortCut.

Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: the document it is pointing to is a html, so this would normally open in a browser displaying a webpage. applyig this logic above, the document now opens in an editor in SharePoint. So close. I gotta check with users as to why they are requiring this. Thank you.

Comment: let me know if it worked

Comment: yes and no. The shortcut opens the *.htm file in SharePoint 2019 to be edited, where if I use the file:// link in a browser the webpage is display. The best solution thus far is to copy and paste the link in SharePoint into a new tab.